# Http 400's to mid tier when server is under stress

Tags: asp.net, .net, asmx, begininvoke, http-status-code-400

I'm working on a project where we have an asp.net website which makes asmx web service calls to a mid tier.  The timeout to the mid tier is 5s.  One thing that we've noticed is that occasionally, at peak traffic times, we get http 400's when calling the mid tier.

We've done a network trace on the website tier for some of these http 400 requests and noticed that 
1) the 3 way tcp handshake goes fast
2) the actual first packet of the post is not initiated until 5 seconds later.  The ack from the first packet of the post comes back quickly
3) a fin ack is sent shortly thereafter (presumably due to timing out), after which the web service tier comes back with the http 400 quickly (the 400 being understandable as the post was incomplete)

Sometimes there is an extra 5s delay before step 3.  Any idea why this may happen?  Step 2 looks like a very strange behavior to me.  Could there be a resource contention causing this delay before the post is sent?  Perhaps some sort of resource that could be configured differently?

We're using the standard .net async methods for making the request (BeginInvoke).  The post body is fully available as a string before we call the api.

I'm thinking the cpu could be too high, causing the delay before 2.  Has anybody seen that before?  I know the cpu is at least 80% during this time.  It could be higher, but our perf counter isn't very high resolution. We're trying to get a higher-resolution perf counter during a repro to confirm that further.  Let me know if you have any other ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified your web.config to allow more concurrent connections to the mid-tier service?